# How do I code an if else PHP statement using sessions as conditions without getting error message?

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I'm using the following php if statement as part of my code

```
if ($_SESSION['username'])
```

and everything is fine when the username session is set, but when it isn't, I get the following error message which I would like to not have show up.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\ebay_tutorial\index.php on line 12
```

How can I improve my code so that the error message doesn't show up?

Comment: You could also modify the error reporting level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your PHP [error reporting level](http://php.net/manual/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is set to show *Notice* errors, which display if you try to access a key in an array which does not exist.

You can stop the error from being displayed by adding a call to [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

Comment: This is correct.
The reason it wasn't working is because $_SESSION['username'] was undefined, but you were trying to use it.